# Pull fork and submit pull request

Tags: github, git-fork

I am working with GitHub and want to submit a pull request. When I fork the repository I don't see my changes I'm guessing because it never asked me where to link the repository to. How do I link the forked repo to a location on my personal computer for the pull request? This is for an interview and with the code done I don't know where (or how) to put it.

I'm the first to oppose noise but I don't know what other exchange site to post on. I'll close it if I'm pointed somewhere else and it doesn't get closed first.

Comment: When you fork from GitHub, normally your local Git should know where to push things to do, ideally this is automatic.

Comment: I downloaded the github desktop app and while it shows what I've done, I can't see it online. It tells me there are no differences between my repo and theirs. I haven't used git in years and I know it's something on my end. The noisy post is me getting desperate.

Comment: Did you push your changes to your fork?

Comment: I tried to but that's half the problem that I don't know how to. I hit the fork button but it doesn't seem to have done anything. I don't know much about git. @CùĐứcHiếu

Comment: Did you see this screen when hitting `fork`? https://www.screencast.com/t/1Sf9K6QbC7O9

Comment: I did but I don't know where it went

Comment: https://github.com/facebook/react & https://github.com/hieucd04/react. Please take a look at both repositories. As you can see from the `Url`, one is owned by `facebook` and the other (my fork) is owned by me. These 2 pages may look identical but there is a critical difference. If you look at the top left corner, you will see: `facebook/react` and `hieucd04/react forked from facebook/react`. the `hieucd04/react
forked from facebook/react` is mine. I can pull/clone that `repo` to my laptop and change anything I want and then push. After that `github.com` will ask if I want to create a PR.

Comment: You should see the same in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have cloned the original repo locally, you can:

- make sure you have a fork on GitHub (you seem to have one, where you say you don't see your changes, which is expected since you haven't push them yet)
- declare that fork as your new origin

That is

```
cd /path/to/my/local/repo
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin https://github.com/<myGitHubAccount>/<reponame.git>
```

Don't forget to add your changes, commit and push:

```
git checkout -b aNewBranch
git add .
git commit -m "Fix done in a new branch for PR (Pull Request)"
git push -u origin aNewBranch
```

From there, you can go to `https://github.com/<myGitHubAccount>/<reponame.git>`, switch to `aNewBranch`, and click "Make a Pull Request"